# Как поступать со служебными файлами Git при развертывании приложения в production?

Tags: git, laravel, развертывание

Есть некое приложение, оно хранится в ну например BitBucket (Git). У этого репозитория есть ветка master, в которую пушат код для production. Код, который находится в работе, разработчики хранят в других ветках, это касается и их локальных репозиториев, и репозитория на BitBucket.

При этом в различных местах приложения есть разнообразные файлы самого Git: .gitignore, .gitattributes, .gitkeep. Есть желание держать их в самом репозитории, дабы разработчики могли бы обмениваться ими. На данный момент эти файлы попадают и в ветку master.

На production приложение разворачивается автоматически из репозитория, в целом не важно при помощи чего (Composer, Capistrano, сам Git, что угодно еще). Вопрос следующий: что делать со служебными файлами Git, которые из ветки master репозитория попадают в production вместе со всеми остальными файлами?

Варианты мне приходят в голову такие:

1. Исключить эти файлы из репозиториев в принципе, пускай каждый разработчик сам себе локально их пишет.
2. Оставить эти файлы в репозиториях во всех ветках, кроме master, то есть обязать разработчиков удалять их из ветки master после мержа/ребейза, перед тем, как запушить ее в репозиторий на BitBucket.
3. Удалять эти файлы посредством некоего скрипта после разворачивания на production, скрипт будет запускаться после деплоя тем или иным инструментом.
4. Оставить эти файлы в покое, так как они хоть и абсолютно не нужны на production, но все равно никак не нарушат его работу и не ослабят защищенность приложения, в силу того, что они все скрытые и веб-сервер их никому не отдаст просто так.
5. Ваш вариант.

Comment: Вариант 4, если мучает паранойя - вариант 3. Не нужно усложнять разработчикам жизнь тем, что может сделать скрипт.

Comment: @cronfy, согласен, но возможно, мы просто не знаем какой-либо достаточно простой и очевидный workflow, чтобы исключать эти файлы? Типа какого-нибудь хитрого варианта ребейза или мержа, настроек Git, прочего.

Comment: Не надо использовать Git для развертывания на сервер - этим вы автоматически ограничиваете себя в возможностях. Есть же инструменты для непрерывной интеграции...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это просто как один из вариантов, написано было о нем к тому, что с какой стороны к задаче не подступись, все равно встает вопрос об обсуждаемых временных файлах. Но спасибо за совет, кому-то наверняка пригодится!

Comment: вы можете использовать `git archive`, тогда `.git` не попадет на сервер

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, спасибо за напоминание про эту команду, по сути она тут ни к чему, но натолкнула на исследование в сторону хуков. Попробую отыскать либо готовый в англоязычном секторе интернета, ну или может напишу сам и выложу тут тогда отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 4):

На вашем месте я бы остановился на 4 варианте. Вы и сами неплохо описали почему.

Если есть желание сделать на продакшене все "красиво" - можно выбрать 3-й вариант. Не думаю, что ради этого стоит специально заморачиваться, но если у вас будут скрипты по сборке приложения в которые можно органично добавить исключение этих файлов - почему бы и нет.

Comment: В целом да, согласен, но я тут вспомнил про пятый вариант - это вариант с написанием хуков для самого Git. Попробую либо найти готовый вариант, либо написать самому, и выложу тогда тут отдельным ответом.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это частный случай 4-го варианта. Да, если вы деплоите приложение с использованием git - вы можете написать хуки, которые будут исключать эти файлы при чекауте (или типа того). Но вообще, думаю, что хуки в git тут стоит использовать разве что для запуска деплоя, который уже выполняется спец. софтом (скриптом). Возможно, я вас как-то не так понял - тогда интересно будет посомтреть что вы найдете =)

Comment: Да, не совсем верно - хук можно написать на все случаи жизни, в том числе на мерж/ребейз веток в локальном репозитории. То есть разработчикам будет достаточно один раз разослать этот скрипт и разместить его в нужном месте в .git\hooks.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите сказать, это будет хук, который будет убирать файлы при мердже в мастер? То есть это будет 2-й вариант. Если в этот раз я понял правильно - то я бы не советовал так делать. Что вам это даст? Разве что проблемы в случае, если вы как-то захотите изменить правила работы с ветками. Или, например, надо вам быстро посмотреть дифф между двумя коммитами (один из них в мастере, а другой нет) - и будет у вас в диффе куча этих файлов.